# Import data from Excel sheet into table SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have an Excel sheet containing data on my PC. I want to export this data into a table stored in SQL Server 2005 database. Import / Export wizard doesn't show the option of importing from Excel sheets present on my PC into a table on SQL Server but only between DATABASES present on SQL Server.

I read that I have to move excel sheet to SQL server and then write queries. Where exactly do I have to move the excel sheet  ?

It would be of great help if somebody can help me out how to proceed step by step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using this  right click on the database and go to task click on 
in that select  export or import database  select the Excel sheet  source 
and then select database table which have same structure
 or else follow this links
[enter link description here](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3580216/SQL-Server-2005-Import--Export-Wizard.htm)

Comment: Missed out the Excel spreadsheet option while trying Import wizard earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Try using SQLWorkbench(open source). You could easily import data from the excel onto your tables, provided the excel and database have same structure